# Exception not caught in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have problem with exception catching in Qt.

Here is my code:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...
void MainWindow::on_editFanButton_clicked()
{
    Fan *fan = 0;
    try
    {
        fan = new Fan(this->selectedFanId(),this);
        connect(fan,SIGNAL(edited()),this,SLOT(fanEdited()));
        fan->edit();

    }
    catch(QString e)
    {
        delete fan;
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Błąd",e);
    }
}
...
```

**fan.cpp**

```
void Fan::edit()
{
    FanEdit *fanEdit = new FanEdit(this);
    connect(fanEdit,SIGNAL(fanEdited()),this,SLOT(fanEdited()));
    fanEdit->show();
}
void Fan::fanEdited()
{
    emit edited();
}
...
```

**fanedit.cpp**

```
void FanEdit::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    DatabaseConnector *databaseConnector = 0;
    databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector();

    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery();
    if(peselChanged)
    {
        query->prepare("select * from kibic where pesel= :pesel");
        query->bindValue(":pesel",ui->peselEdit->text());
        query->exec();
        if(query->next()) throw QString("Kibic o podanym numerze pesel już istnieje!");
    }

    ...

}
```

I'm getting program terminated error when throw exception in `void FanEdit::on_saveButton_clicked()`. Probably it terminate because exception has not been caught.

Where should I catch exception? In mainwindow.cpp or in fan.cpp and rethrow it?

Comment: Add `catch(...)` clause in `on_editFanButton_clicked()` and see if you get there.

Comment: You should post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `FanEdit::on_saveButton_clicked()` is not called from `MainWindow::on_editFanButton_clicked()`. You have to wrap `FanEdit::on_saveButton_clicked()` into a try-catch block:

```
void FanEdit::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    try
    {
       // code goes here
    } 
    catch (...)
    {
       // don't rethrow
    }
}
```

You must not rethrow your exception because [Qt doesn't like it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html).